Interpretation of the ideal gas single particle partition function
When considering an ideal gas composed of identical particles, in the semi-classical case, one can find that the single particle partition function is equal to:
$$Z(1,T,V) = \frac{V}{\Lambda^3},$$
with $V$ the volume of the box and $\Lambda$ the thermal De Broglie wavelength. The cube of this wavelength can be thought of as the mean volume occupied by a quantum particle.
Thus, I assume that $\frac{V}{\Lambda^3}$ is equal to the mean number of particles that can fit in the volume.
Furthermore, the partition function is the sum total number of accessible states, where each state is weighted by the associated Boltzmann factor. So, $Z(1,T,V)$ Could be thought of as some sort of effective number of states accessible to the particle.
Here comes the part that troubles me. How can the """number of particles that can fit on average in the real space volume"""" be related to the number of states ?

In fact, it is not clear why one can assume that $V/\Lambda^3$ is equal to the average number of particles that can fit into a volume $V$. What is the distribution of the number of particles from which this average could be determined? In the theory of a quantum ideal Fermi gas, it is known that a dense system with a much larger number of particles,
$$
N \gg \frac{V}{\Lambda^3},
$$
is strongly degenerate, i.e. "very quantum" with strong effects due to the Pauli exclusion principle, whereas a system with a much smaller number of particles,
$$
N \ll \frac{V}{\Lambda^3},\tag{1}
$$
is nondegenerate, i.e. semiclassical. From the first of these inequalities it is clear that $V/\Lambda^3$ does not have the meaning of the maximum possible number of particles that can fit in a volume $V$, and from both inequalities it follows that this value also does not coincide with the number of particles in the system. Thus, it turns out that $V/\Lambda^3$ is simply the number of “boxes” with sides of length $\Lambda$ into which the volume $V$ can be divided.
In the case of a semiclassical gas, this “number of boxes”, $Z(1,T,V)$, can indeed be considered as the effective number of possible states of one particle, then, by virtue of inequality (1), the statistical sum of a semiclassical gas of $N$ identical particles
$$
Z(N,T,V) = \frac{(Z(1,T,V))^N}{N!}\tag{2}
$$
can be considered as the effective number of states of a multiparticle system.
I am not sure if such an interpretation of $Z(1,T,V)$ is possible in the case of a degenerate gas.
Update. Regarding the “intuition behind why exactly the effective number of states coincides with the number of boxes”, I can say the following. There is a simple logic that leads to inequality (1) as a criterion for the quasi-classicality of a gas. The motion can be considered quasi-classical in cases where the characteristic de Broglie wavelength is small compared to other length scales of the problem. In gases, the natural length scale is the characteristic distance between particles, $a = (V/N)^{1/3}$. Therefore, one can expect that quantum effects, in particular particle statistics, are unimportant when the following inequality, equivalent to (1), holds:
$$
a \gg \Lambda.
$$
Now, if we imagine placing $N$ quantum particles in a characteristic semiclassical configuration in a volume $V$, this should look like $N$ non-intersecting de Broglie wave packets with different wavelengths with scale $\Lambda$. How can we guarantee that different wave packets are likely to not intersect? We can say that there are boxes and particles are likely (due to inequality (1)) to occupy different boxes. What will be the name of the number of boxes? It seems quite natural to say that it is the number of states of one particle.
Frankly, I find this logic artificial. In my opinion, it creates even more "whys" that I don't have the energy to discuss. To mention some

particles state is characterized not only by position, but also by momentum, which was here integrated out some how;

Characteristic quantities are defined by order of magnitude, for example $\Lambda \sim \hbar/\sqrt{mk_BT}$, so how are we so lucky that we guessed the "correct" definition to within a constant factor?

and even why do we talk about statistical sums as numbers of states at all when they also contain energy, $Z \sim \Gamma e^{-E/kT}$?


In connection with the last question, for me one of the most convincing reasons is formula (2) taking into account inequality (1).

But then, is there a deeper intuition behind why exactly the effective number of states coincides with the number of boxes ?

@Lucas, I don't really believe in intuition. I think it usually comes after writing down exact formulas. However, I will update my answer later.


Here comes the part that troubles me. How can the """number of particles that can fit on average in the real space volume"""" be related to the number of states ?

Statistical physics assumes thermodynamiuc limit, i.e., it is strictly speaking valid only for the systems with an infinite number of particles, while preserving finite density (and some other parameters):
$$
N\rightarrow \infty, V\rightarrow\infty, \text{ but } \frac{N}{V}=\text{const}
$$
Now, when we deal with the Grand canonical ensemble, we deal with a system composed of what we call system and the reservoir/bath. It is the number of particles of the system+reservoir that is taken to infinity, which allows us to consider, in principle, treat even systems with a finite number of particles using thermodynamic machinery (e.g., describing them by a  Boltzmann distribution), although this would be meaningless (or at least incorrect), if the system was isolated (from the bath/reservoir.)
Thus, e.g., we can apply Boltzmann distribution to a single atom, stating that the occupation probabilities of its energy states are given by Boltzmann distribution:
$$
p_n\propto e^{-\frac{E_n}{k_BT}}.
$$
We imply here that the atom is coupled to the electromagnetic field (black body radiation) of temperature $T£ or/and that it is one of many atoms in a gas, where the atomic collisions may change inner states of atoms or something like that.
Likewise, a single energy level is often described as broadened, i.e. having a smooth energy of states rather than a sharp peak - what is meant here is that the actual eigenstates of the system+reservoir form a continuous spectrum, and we speak on their projection on an atomic state (which is not an eigenstate of the whole system.)
That the number of particles in a certain volume is fractional (and less than 1) simply means that some of the allowed states of system+bath have a particle in the volume of interests, while others don't.
